# Defining a generic based on react prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define a generic type based on the type of a prop.
The implementation looks something like

```
interface ChildrenProps<T> {
  values: T;
  errors: T;
}

interface FormHandlerProps<T> {
  initialValues: T;
  children: React.FC<ChildrenProps<T>>;
}

export function FormHandler<T>({
  children,
  initialValues,
}: FormHandlerProps<typeof initialValues>) {
  const [values] = useState<typeof initialValues>(initialValues)

  return(
     <>
        children({values})
     </>
  )

}
```

However when I implement as below, 'values' is defined as 'any'

```
<FormHandler
    initialValues={{name: 'test', address: 'test'}}
>

{({values}) => (
    <p> {values.name} </p>
    <p> {values.address} </p>
    <p> {values.foobar} </p> // SHOULD BE INVALID
)}


</FormHandler>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't define the type of `initialValues` in terms of `typeof initialValues`; the compiler sees that as circular and doesn't know what to do.  It bails out by giving it the `any` type:

```
export function FormHandler<T>({
    children, initialValues
    // -----> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // 'initialValues' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type 
    // annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
}: FormHandlerProps<typeof initialValues>) { /* ... */ }
```

You should have seen a compiler warning to this effect as shown above, assuming you are using the [`--noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) or [`--strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) compiler options.  If you're not, you really should consider it, since it does a good job of catching errors.

---

Anyway, the fix here is to just give the argument an explicit type that is not self-referential:

```
export function FormHandler<T>({
    children, initialValues
}: FormHandlerProps<T>) {
    const [values] = useState<typeof initialValues>(initialValues)

    return (
        <>
            children({values})
        </>
    )
}
```

And then the rest of your code should hopefully work as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUKJLHAEp2OnmU0eTZqwB2+KCQYEAwgAtgAGwAmtUQAVyYVAB4AKgD5EzOKbgA3HIuTpUALjh6A3CbPoo5KPccvCI4OLuUvQEAGLQIAASOKLKiu6aENr6RgiupgHAMMBWAGpWNt7O6XD0CipqDtwMMAB0oTI68kqq6BpauoYGviLoAB7s8CTIoozAEKJw4VBRMXHuAEI4yikAFGlmpeWtogA0cJnZeQW2JQD0Z3AAtDc3RgB+j0-PT+eXVIc5ivnWtlQH4EUwHoWUUAE84HIcKg4DAwWACFQYmD-gAjdD0HBoAhZODKCC2OCiCDwKHmAg4WHwghvOAxYm4bITOmxA4w2gkdxtELKPHAWiMcFwaAHWL8jEwIUBA4wGEQADuk0+VmAAC93LVmIQHNNZrF4lBEsk4QiICRRVkvj9CgYAJTGTb0CaoeAAbUsv1QAF04ABeFAYbB4dA6E3oM0Wo7fE6oAyrZXRz22kSbWgwZBQSarEqbHQGHObMxlFpqdYewqEZOFsw6M75zbJvy9AbQIYjMbM3XRfXuNYbIvbNT7BPW07aqYRbvzQ0dFL2-umJ2iF1wd0xn3+7FB-Ch6kRkcxuMHpMpsxpjNZgumPNXwvFiptMsxyu32v1syNkTMHRduYGkrHoUvoIEgog4CA6AOFQ+AulQ+zLK0qDeNBthMEQfjvqYCDrBYMZEPavpGKsOjVIw9RQDgADmEHiJhhY6GAqTlrYtRgRBxC1oxr6MYgzGoLUCG0EhHFnFx1bXjxCB8bUJAQBAqI4FAIk8RcooesAyglLWpF1KEFHUW0MB0bafi1r+PZQAYQA)

Comment: I would change the `useState` to `useState<T>` instead of `useState<typeof initialValues>` just to keep it clean.  They are not going to be able to call `children` because they defined it such that both `values` and `errors` are required. And `errors` has the same type as `values` which makes no sense.  They probably want something like `interface ChildrenProps<T> { values: T; errors: Partial<Record<keyof T, Error>>; }`